# Interpolation based on a known curve

Tags: curve-fitting, interpolation

I have 6 datasets, 1 of which has 20 points, the other five have only 2 (beginning and end points). I want to interpolate 18 intervening points into the 2 point datasets such that the resulting curves are similar to/match the curve defined by the 20 point data set. An important note is that the complete, 20-point data set and the other five are significantly different in their orders of magnitude: the 20-pt set starts at 150 and ends at 720000, while the other data sets are (1,31.25), (2,62.5), (4,125), (8,250), & (16,500). I am unclear of the proper terminology for what I am trying to do, and thus have had a very hard time finding the correct documentation/instruction.

Can any of you provide the correct terminology, and/or describe how to go about what I'm trying to accomplish? I'm working with a spreadsheet program for the sake of ease, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This has been sitting here for a day, without even a comment, so I will try to answer,
even though you did not explain why you want to do this,
or give the 20 values in the one complete dataset. (Unsure what 'curve' you're referring to.)

I'm not sure it is
a good idea to interpolate between maximum and minimum
values of a "dataset" in this way, but here is one way
to do it in R based on simple algebra. [It's analogous to converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius temperatures.]

Let `x1` have 20 observations from 92 to 6938 with range 6846:

```
sort(x1)
 [1]   92  568  717  839 1154 1354 1644 1973 2672 2802
[11] 3176 3503 3917 3926 4109 4302 4347 4430 4601 6938
```

Let `x2` have minimum 4 and maximum 125, with range 121.
Then let

```
x2 = (121/6846)*(x1 - 92) + 4
```

so that "interpolated" `x2` has values as follows:

```
sort(x2)
 [1]   4.00000  12.41309  15.04660  17.20289  22.77038
 [6]  26.30529  31.43091  37.24584  49.60035  51.89804
[11]  58.50833  64.28791  71.60517  71.76424  74.99869
[16]  78.40987  79.20523  80.67222  83.69457 125.00000


par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 stripchart(x1, pch="|", main="x1")
 stripchart(x2, pch="|", main="x2")
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
```

[image]